# In kivy, how can I use android toast method?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I want to display a message box while running my app when there's some events.
Is it possible to use pyJNIus to access toast?

Answer (score 1):

Knappador has a [project for this](https://github.com/knappador/kivy-toaster), that includes a toast emulation on non-android devices.

You can also check the code there to see how this is achieved with pyjnius, it's simple to do this yourself to call the android toast api directly.

Comment: and its' improved version in [KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/tree/master/kivymd/toast)